# Is there a keybinding for absolute value?

Tags: notebooks, keyboard

Is there a keyboard shortcut or esc-sequence for typing in the absolute value bars into input cells?  I know that if you do,

```
Abs[-4] // TraditionalForm
```

and copy the output into an input cell using the "Paste literal" option, you get functioning absolute value bars with a placeholder.  I'm curious if there's a less roundabout way to obtain them.

Comment: You can define your own function to follow this form: `BracketingBar[x_] := Abs[x]`

Comment: That give the traditional notation in the output (for arguments that are not numeric), but not in input. O.P. requested the notation in Input cells.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a built-in keybinding, but you can define one yourself:

```
ClearAll[myAbs]

appearanceAbs[x_] := 
 TemplateBox[{x}, "myAbs", 
  DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", 
       "\[NoBreak]", #1, "\[NoBreak]", "\[RightBracketingBar]"}] &), 
  InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"myAbs", "[", #1, "]"}] &)]

myAbs[x_?NumericQ] := Abs[x]

myAbs /: MakeBoxes[myAbs[x_], _] := appearanceAbs[ToBoxes[x]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Join[{"abs" -> appearanceAbs["\[SelectionPlaceholder]"]}, 
    InputAliases /. 
      Quiet[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]] /. 
     InputAliases -> {}]]
```

This adds a shortcut <kbd>Esc</kbd>`abs`<kbd>Esc</kbd> to the notebook's `InputAliases`. When you type it, a template will appear that looks the way one expects, $|\square|$. You may have to tab into it (that's a bug that didn't exist in older versions), and it will evaluate as `Abs` if the argument you entered is numeric. Otherwise, the display will remain of the form you see in `TraditionalForm` output. The evaluation of `Abs` happens because I define the template with an `InterpretationFunction`. I restrict this to numeric arguments, and for the other cases there is the definition  `myAbs /: MakeBoxes` which kicks in when an unevaluated template is to be displayed again. To make this case distinction possible, I define an intermediate function `myAbs`.

Answer (score 11):

If one does not mind occupying [`BracketingBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BracketingBar.html) this can be done quite cleanly.

```
MakeBoxes[Abs[x_], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes @ BracketingBar[x]

BracketingBar = Abs;
```

This provides bidirectoinal translation, i.e. `Abs[x]` is formatted with bars, and also it may be entered with the special characters `\[LeftBracketingBar]` and `\[RightBracketingBar]`, entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>L</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Alternatively one may use the Notation Package to set up bidirectional or unidirectional translation.

Comment: Do you mind adding how you would go about this using the Notation Package? Fine with asking as a separate question if you'd prefer.

Comment: @Sterling I have been away from Stack Exchange.  Did you solve this in the interim?

Comment: No worries. I haven't solved this yet.