# Formatting the output of Abs[x] to look like $|x|$

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I have a program where I deal with multiple complex variables and it is convenient to ouput all absolute values and complex conjugates as $|x|$ and $x^*$. To achieve this, I've added these lines to my code:

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate /: MakeBoxes[Conjugate[x_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[{Parenthesize[x, StandardForm, Power]}, "Conjugate", DisplayFunction -> (SuperscriptBox[#1, "*"] &)]
Protect[Conjugate];

Unprotect[Abs];
Abs := StringForm["|``|", #1] &
Protect[Abs];
```

The lines for Conjugate work well, but the ones for Abs are problematic. Whenever I copy-paste the output of Abs[x], the in-line command looks like this:

```
StringForm["|``|", x]
```

instead of Abs[x] or |x|.
Is there a better way to tell Mathematica how to format this absolute value?.

Comment: I assume wrapping the whole expression in `TraditionalForm` isn't what you want, and in fact you just want these to be formatted in place to make reading easier while still having computability?  Also [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) might be worth looking at.

Comment: Use `Abs /: MakeBoxes[Abs[x_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]}, "Abs"]`

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a keybinding for absolute value?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109028/245)

Comment: @CarlWoll Wow, I never noticed the relationship between `TemplateBox` and `TraditionalForm`! This should really be posted as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myFormat[f_] := (Unprotect@f;
  Format[f[x_], StandardForm] := Activate@TraditionalForm[Inactive@f[x]] (*Watch out for recursion!*);
 Protect@f)

myFormat /@ {Abs, Conjugate};

{Abs[x], Conjugate[x]}^2
% /. x -> I
```

[image: Displayed output of the code]

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would strongly recommend you don't redefine Abs and Conjugate, but obviously that's your perogative.

Second, it's difficult to understand what you want. You say that you want the output of your re-defined Abs to be Abs[x] or |x|, but what would that even mean? It can't be Abs[x], because Abs is a function that you've redefined to produce a StringForm expression. As for |x|, that's not a valid Mathematica expression. Maybe you meant it to be string: "|x|". If you want that string, that can be accommodated, but I don't know what value that has for you.

Anyway, here are four alternatives for doing the formatting (each shows slightly different strategies):

```
Format[AbsHold1A[expr_]] := StringForm["|``|", expr];
Format[AbsHold1B[expr_]] := "|" <> ToString[expr] <> "|";

SetAttributes[{AbsHold2A, AbsHold2B}, HoldAll];
Format[AbsHold2A[expr_]] := StringForm["|``|", ToString@Unevaluated[expr]];
Format[AbsHold2B[expr_]] := "|" <> ToString[Unevaluated@expr] <> "|";
```

Now you can apply one of these new heads instead of Abs:

```
AbsHold1A[-5] (* displays as |-5| *)
(* the other three also display as |-5| *)

x = -5;
AbsHold1A[x] (* the 1 versions display as |-5| *)
AbsHold2A[x] (* the 2 versions display as |x| *)
```

With this approach, you still have a value that you can evaluate. One way would be to set UpValues with regard to Abs:

```
Abs[abs_AbsHold1A] ^:= Abs @@ abs
(* do the same for the other three *)
```

But, if you want the output of AbsForm to actually be the string, e.g. "|x|", then just define it directly rather than using Format:

```
AbsHold3A[expr_] := StringForm["|``|", expr];
AbsHold3B[expr_] := "|" <> ToString[expr] <> "|"
(* and so forth for the other two, making sure to set the necessary attributes *)
```

If you want to retrieve the value, you'll have to do something to destructure the string/stringform:

```
StringTake[ToString[AbsHold3A[x]], {2, -2}];
StringTake[AbsHold3B[x], {2, -2}];
```

Comment: hmm. Based on the other answers, maybe I misunderstood. If you're literally doing this with just pure symbols whose evaluation you don't need to suppress, then yeah, the other answers are simpler. I interpreted "variables" to mean things that might have assigned values.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the simple and surprising solution in [Carl Woll's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267632/formatting-the-output-of-absx-to-look-like-x#comment667185_267632) to an answer:

```
Unprotect[Abs];
Abs /: MakeBoxes[Abs[x_], StandardForm] := 
  TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm]}, "Abs"]
Protect[Abs];
```